# GraphQl request from Strapi only returning 10 items

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client, strapi

Having a problem with GraphQl in Strapi where my query is only reuturning 10 items when there are more in the database. I have the amountLimit:100 in the plugins config file set, but I have tried altering that number to be lower than 10 to test, and i still always get 10 results so not sure if this is hooked up right for the graphQl plug in (the clouldinary config within the same file is working great). Regardless, all documentation I have read about strapi and the graphql plug in states that it should return up to 100 automatically.
On the frontend I am using NextJS and apollo client to query, not sure if that would have anything to do with it. This is my first time working with graphql, so not sure if i am missing something -
Any suggestions?

query in nextjs:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { API_URL } = process.env
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: `${API_URL}`,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
    query getArtworks {
      artworks(sort: ["people.lastName", "yearStarted:desc"]) {
        data {
          id
          attributes {
            RFQ,
            people {
              data {
                attributes {
                  lastName
                }
              }
            }
            title,
            yearStarted,
            yearEnded,
            description,
            materials,
            dimensions,
            location,
            client,
            media {
              data {
                attributes {
                  url,
                  caption,
                  width,
                  height
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `
  });

  return {
    props: {
      artworks: data.artworks,
    }
  }
}
```

in plugins.js in config on strapi

```
graphql: {
    enabled: true,
    endpoint: "/graphql",
    shadowCRUD: true,
    playgroundAlways: true,
    depthLimit: 10,
    amountLimit: 100,
    introspection: true,
    apolloServer: {
      tracing: false,
    },
  },
```

strapi deployed through heroku

Comment: Hey there. Please could you share some code, perhaps your graphQL query and some of your config files?

Comment: @adrian sorry updated!

Comment: Did you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70752976/graphql-retrieves-only-maximum-10-items-from-strapi#answer-70753118). It could be helpful to you.

Comment: @Pierre Wow thank you so much for sending that!!!!!!  it was the cause I needed to set the pagination limit and max limit with the keys graphql.config.defaultLimit and graphql.config.maxLimit

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to see it helped. Have fun using Strapi.